# How to stop a thread if it won't stop itself?

Tags: java, multithreading

in a java Runnable, I usually write a loop, like

```
while(running) {
   ......
}
```

Then set the running to `false` could make the thread stop.
But if the runnable is a long process without any loop, and cannot controlled by any tags.
How to make a thread stop in another thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The long process might accept Thread.interrupt() so try that first. (though unlikely)

As a last resort you can use Thread.stop(), however you should read the warnings for this method.

The only safe way to stop a thread, is to place it in a seperate process and kill the process to stop it.

Comment: Thread.interrupt() does not work, it seems only can cause a inturruptexception if the thread is in sleep.
Thread.stop() works, but its not safe, I think

Comment: @Peter: I don't suppose there's a "standard .NET way" of dealing with "worker processes", is there?

Comment: @user725085, Thread.stop() is not safe depending on what the thread happens to be doing at the time. Thats why you need to read the warning and the code you have to stop.  However, it may be your only option.

Comment: @corlettk, I am sure there is, but I don't have much of a clue about .NET. ;)

Comment: @Peter: DOH! I meant Java... LanguageShiftFailException... It's been a year since I touched Java ;-)

Comment: @corlettk, I would say the best practice way is to use an ExecutorService to submit tasks and use Future.cancel(true) to stop them.  This requires that the tasks be short lived or honour Thread.interrupt().

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there are a couple of ways.

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.interrupt();
t.stop();
t.destroy();
```

I would not advice for the later 2 as they can cause problems if they hold a lock from a synchronized object etc.

EDIT: Typo

Comment: interrupt is the only safe one,  you cannot resume a stopped thread. you cannot even call start() more than once.

Comment: Actually, `interrupt` is preferred over `stop` or `destroy`, for the reasons you mention. EDIT: beat me @Peter!

Comment: destroy is not a good choice as it throws NoSuchMethodError (as per javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 yourThread.sleep(interval);
```

or

```
  yourThread.stop();
```

Comment: The first one doesn't do what you suggest, it sleeps the current thread as its a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Long running processes usually do have some loops. I can't imagine a long running algorithm that is coded without..

So even if you don't have a classic outer `while` loop, you can still add your checks against `running` to the inner loops in the algorithm.

(Exception: blocking I/O, socket based tasks. But that's a different story - even if you read from a stream, there is at least one loop where you can add a stop check)

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense. I/O and sleep seems can be handled by InturrptException.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend `stop()` as it is deprecated, and may not even work on future JVMs.

The safest way is to stop the thread with `interrupt()` and have the thread make its own checks to `isInterrupted()` - this will require the insertion of some checks unfortunately.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you cannot do that. Thread only stops itself, all the other options are dangerous/hacky/non-portable. If you thread is in the main loop, you send it a signal, the thread shoudl react and stop by itself (in Java it is done with interrupt mechanism).

If you thread doesn't behave like this - consider this is a bug that should be fixed ASAP.